# keeping user profile information inside same database as user login information

Tags: php, mysql, database

Which would be the best route to take designing my database tables?

I have two scenarios of how I can setup my database tables for users

1) I use the `users` table to include user id, email, username, password, first name, last name, and all other profile data

2) I have `users` table to JUST store the id, email, password and login information and then use `userprofile` table to store all the profile data.

Which would be the better route to take not knowing how big a website will get in the future?

I'm trying to do things the right way now rather than realize later I should have done it a different way.

Thanks in advance for all suggestions!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there's a one-to-one relationship between User and UserProfile, I would just recommend storing them in the same table, unless you have significant indexing requirements that differ for each set of data.

Comment: I fixed my question to reflect tables instead of databases, my apologies.  Thank you for your input.  So storing all of this in one table shouldn't slow down a site compared to storing in two tables correct?  (I'm thinking of the scenario where if people are viewing profiles and others are logging in)

Comment: Having a single table really shouldn't slow anything down.  If you get to that point you should really look at your indexes and optimize them as much as possible.  If you have two tables with a one-to-one relationship, then you just have one extra index that you could eliminate by combining the tables, so if anything it would take performance away by having two.  The only time I would suggest you break it up into multiple tables is if you have a lot of columns (like 50+).  Normalizing data doesn't really apply to a one-to-one relationship

Comment: Awesome, thank you for your help.  I will accept your answer when time limit is up.